# v-select component from child to parent binding when editing

Tags: vue.js

I'm running again another issue on my code, that although I can save the `v-select` component. I have 2 of these, the another is good in which the type items are object. The problem is by clicking edit button and passing value from child component to parent component, when I console the issue in edit method, I can see the output in console but it does not display on the imported component which is *claimsdropdown*. And when I update the another `v-select` imported component named type, the *claimsdropdown* value is passing null, that although it has already value in it based on fetching from database.

Here is my *v-select* component stuff:

```
<template>
  <v-select
    :items="items"
    item-text="text"
    item-value="value"
    v-model="selected"
    return-object
    :menu-props="{ bottom: true, offsetY: true }"
    append-icon="fas fa-chevron-down"
    placeholder="Claims"
    outlined
    dense
  />
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex"

export default {
  name: "ClaimsDropdown",
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      {
        text: "Yes",
        value: true
      },
      {
        text: "No",
        value: false
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      selected: state => state.projects.selected
    }),
    selected: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.projects.selected;
      },
      set(item) {
        this.$store.commit("projects/SET_SELECTED", {
          selected: item.value
        });
        this.$store.commit("projects/SET_FILTER_IS_CLAIMED", {
          is_claimed: item?.value
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

*Parent Component*:

```
<v-row>
  <v-col cols="4">
   <ClaimsDropdown v-model="this.selected.claim" />
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

on my computed:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    selected: state => state.projects.selected

  })
}
```

and on method edit:

```
this.selected.claim = getFilterPresetsData.filters.claimed;
console.log({checkingClaim: this.selected.claim}); //display whatever the value from database.
```

Vuex: *projects* >name of vuex store

```
state: selected: null
```

my brain got drain by this one.